# Can someone help me understand DC-DC circuit in these microphones?

Tags: audio, switch-mode-power-supply

I have trouble understanding those two circuits. I know they are DC-DC converters, but I am not sure how they work.

Here is the dc converter in a Neumann U89, I am maily straggling with the two transistors at the right hand side. Do they form an oscillator or it is something else?

[image: U89i DC converter]

Also, here is the DC converter circuit on a Sony C37P, I am just wondering what type of oscillator it is, and how it works.
[image: Sony C-37P DC -DC converter]

Thanks

Comment: Hello! Top appears to be a traditional Hartley common-collector oscillator, using a composite (cascode JFET + BJT) arrangement for... probably very little reason? Maybe they lacked suitable component ratings at the time, I have no idea. The second one lacks a feedback path and I can only assume is incorrectly traced/drawn.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate them?